# Dynamically Generating ORM Classes

Tags: ruby, orm, metaprogramming, sinatra

I'm working on a Sinatra-based project that uses the Datamapper ORM. I'd like to be able to define criteria for the DM validations in an external YAML file so that less-experienced users of the system can easily tweak the setup. I have this working pretty well as a proof-of-concept, but I suspect there could be a much easier or a least less processor-intensive way to approach this.

Right now, the script loads the YAML file and generates the DM classes with a series of eval statements (I know this already places me on thin ice). The problem is that this process has to happen with every request. My bright idea is to check the YAML for changes, regenerate the classes and export to static source if changes are detected, and include the static files if no changes are detected.

This is proving more difficult than I anticipated because exporting code blocks to strings for serialization isn't as trivial as I expected.

Is this ridiculous? Am I approaching this in an entirely wrong-headed way?

I'm new to Ruby and the world of ORMs, so please forgive my ignorance.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought in Ruby you don't have to _generate_ anything. Everything is just one _closure_ a away.

Answer (score 1):

> DM validations in an external YAML file so that less-experienced users of the system can easily tweak the setup

A DSL for a DSL. Not having seen your YAML I still wonder how much easier than the DM Validations it really can get?

```
require 'dm-validations'
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :name, String
  # Manual validation
  validates_length_of :name, :max => 42

  # Auto-validation 
  property :bio, Text, :length => 100..500
end
```

Instead of going for YAML I would provide the *less-experienced* users with a couple of relevant validation examples and possibly also a short guideline based on the [dm-validations documentation](http://datamapper.org/docs/validations).

Comment: This absolutely makes sense, though I do think I have good reason in this situation to shield users from the source. Still, your response and the others I've received have convinced me that I am indeed barking up the wrong tree!

Answer (score 0):

It does seem a little crazy to go and put everything in YAML, as that's only a shade easier than writing the validations in Ruby. What you could do is make a DSL in Ruby that makes defining validations much easier, then expose that to your users instead of the whole class.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree that I'm probably making the situation needlessly complex with my current strategy. I think I'm going to retreat back to the drawing board on this one. Thanks again.